# SUM(data) gives different output

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT finished.first_name, sum(manpower_used.salary) AS 'salary',  
       materials_used.qty * materials_used.price AS 'Total' 
from finished 
INNER JOIN manpower_used ON finished.order_number=manpower_used.order_number
INNER JOIN materials_used ON manpower_used.order_number=materials_used.order_number
```

and I'm getting this output:

> first_name | salary | Total 
>  Aaron Sean | 840    | 32.5

I'm getting the wrong output in my salary column which is the correct output should be 210 (Since I have 3 70's in my salary column) but it gives me 840

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should use group by manpower_used.order_number

Comment: Try the same query with `manpower_used.salary` instead of `sum(manpower_used.salary)`. You might then get an idea, why your result is 4x the expected one.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone It loops until the end of query. How to stop the loop when there is nothing to check already?